# Snowflake INNER JOIN results in Error: NULL result in a Non-Nullable Column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using the following query to inner join two tables. The columns I join on, are both of type varchar.

However when I use the following query, it results in Error:
**NULL result in a Non-Nullable Column**

"RAW"."DB_FOO"."table" is a standard table.
where EXTERNALID is of type VARCHAR(16777216)

EXTERNALID is NOT DECLARED as a "VARCHAR NOT NULL" in "RAW"."DB_FOO"."table" definition. It is nullable.

"RAW"."DB_BAR"."view"  is a view
where OPP_ID is of type VARCHAR(16777216)

```
SELECT 
   a.EXTERNALID
  ,c.OPP_ID

FROM 
    "RAW"."DB_FOO"."table" AS a
JOIN 
    "RAW"."DB_BAR"."view" AS c
ON 
    a.EXTERNALID = c.OPP_ID
```

When I try to explicity cast the type to varchar the query executes/works

```
SELECT 
   a.column
  ,c.column

FROM 
    "RAW"."DB_FOO"."table" AS a
JOIN 
    "RAW"."DB_BAR"."view" AS c
ON 
    a.EXTERNALID::varchar = c.OPP_ID::varchar
```

I have no idea why is that happening. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the actual definition of table and view. Is the table a standard table or an external table?

Comment: Would be interested to see what is the DDL for the view.

Answer (score -1):

EXTERNALID is declared as a "VARCHAR NOT NULL" in "RAW"."DB_FOO"."table" definition.

Comment: No, It is nullable based on the information i get on when i use DESCRIBE TABLE clause in snwoflake.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).